# Unable to verify the certificate from StartSSL?

Tags: certificate, openssl

I'm new to OpenSSL and I'm unable to verify the certificate from StartSSL.

The command that I tried in order to verify the certificate is:

```
openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem mydomain.com.crt
```

The error I got was :

```
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your "ca.pem" file. I'm guessing it doesn't contain all necessary intermediate certs.

(Sources: Documentation for "verify" -> Error 20. https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/verify.html )

Comment: When the CA delivered the EE cert to the subject they should have provided the appropriate intermediate certs, often as a "bundle". If you are the subject, you can either add these certs (converted to PEM if necessary) to ca.pem, perhaps temporarily, or you can supply them (again in PEM) with `-untrusted`. If you are not the subject, get them from the subject or if they are (correctly) installed on an accessible server, you can get them by doing a connection to that server with `s_client -showcerts`.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get your ca.pem from?

I would recommend going to https://www.startssl.com/certs/ and, as @dave_thompson_085 recommended, getting the correct bundle - for instance, ca-bundle.pem looks pretty good.

This is because StartSSL issues all their certs through intermediates - in the case of Class 1 free certs, the intermediate certs are found in https://www.startssl.com/certs/class1/sha2/pem/ for SHA-2 (which you really should be using) signed Class 1 certs.